# generic term for inductors/capacitors/transformers for power-handling applications

Tags: capacitor, terminology, magnetics, power-electronics

Can anyone think of a generic term to cover capacitors and magnetics for power-handling applications? (is there one?)

I want to distinguish from power semiconductors and signal-level capacitors/magnetics.

Comment: How about passive components, or perhaps impedances. I am assuming that by magnetics you mean inductors.

Comment: inductors, transformers, common-mode chokes, motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard term to differentiate components used for power handling as apposed to signal handling.  Sometimes you hear the term "power magnetics", but I've never heard anything like "power capacitors".  There are certainly "power transistors" versus "small signal" or "switching" transistors.

Even if you find a term, it would be dangerous to use without definition anyway.  In general, it's good to be clear and explicit without relying on specialized terms unless you are really sure they will be understood as intended.

Just say what you mean.